# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all' when connecting my model to admin

Tags: python, django

Getting an `'list' object has no attribute all` error based on my function in my admin class.

```
    def get_stocks(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([s.stock_list for s in obj.stock_list.all()])
```

The error seems very trivial, in fact I know what the problem is, but I don't get why Im getting the error for this specific function and not the one above, aka `def get_users()`

Here is my admin.py file

```
@admin.register(models.Bucket)
class BucketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 
    list_display = ('id','owner','category', 'get_users', 'name', 'created',
                    'slug','stock_count','get_stocks', 'about')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }


    def get_users(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([u.user_name for u in obj.users.all()])
        print(u)
    
    def get_stocks(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([s.stock_list for s in obj.stock_list.all()])
```

Here is the model in question

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('social', 'Social'),
    )


    class BucketObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(Bucket.owner)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=options)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True) 
    stock_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    objects = models.Manager()
    bucketobjects = BucketObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stock_count = Bucket.objects.aggregate(Sum('stock_list', distinct=True))
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bucket:bucket-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stock_list
```

Full TraceBack:

```
File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 575, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'get_stocks'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 265, in lookup_field
    f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 296, in _get_non_gfk_field
    field = opts.get_field(name)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 577, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Bucket has no field named 'get_stocks'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/base.py", line 33, in render
    return super().render(context)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 214, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 341, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl)),
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 317, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 308, in __init__
    super().__init__(*items)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 233, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 274, in lookup_field
    value = attr(obj)
  File "/home/andres/stockbuckets.io/bucket/admin.py", line 18, in get_stocks
    return "\n".join([s.stock_list for s in obj.stock_list.all()])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `stock_list` is a list of strings:

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True)
```

so that means that `obj.stock_list` will return a list of strings, not a queryset. This thus means that your process this with:

```
@admin.register(models.Bucket)
class BucketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     # …
    
    def get_stocks(self, obj):
        return '\n'.join(obj.stock_list)
```

It might however *not* be a good idea to use an `ArrayField`. If it refers to another model, `Stock` for example, it is better to use a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) this guarantees *referential integrity*: by using an array of strings, if later you remove the stock, then there are still items in the `stock_list` with that name.

Comment: ArrayField is it’s own self, does not refer to any model. I was planning to have stock_list in a many2many relationship, However it seemed like a chaotic way to create the dB ( correct me if I’m wrong). The only reason why I used arrayfield was to quickly pull the object and insert the list as part of an API query. 

I guess I should however reconsider as you said, and switch the relationship to m2m, and then transform the object to a list in the future. Also, want to point out that your code snippet helped solve my original problem from the post.

Comment: @Dre: well only you can of course decide what will be the best, since you know the entire application. The main reason why arrays are often not a good idea is because relational databases (SQL), is not very good with such arrays. Imagine that you later add a `Stock` model, and you add the price to the model, then by using a junction table, you can calculate the total value of a `Bucket` with SQL (and Django), whereas for arrays that will be impossible (or it will be very complicated).

Comment: Yes you have a good point, I actually have my financial data in a separate postgres db. My other db has all my SQL functions. All i need to do is pass the `ArrayField` to my API URL to get the data, for example, price for each stock in `stock_list`.  Thank you for sharing your expertise on the matter, I did not know those downsides of arrayfields.